# MySQL DISTINCT ignored in SELECT displays duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that is joining 3 tables but is displaying duplicate results where I only one instance of a record by using DISTINCT on the r.Email column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, r.Email, ListingID, ListingFirmID
    FROM sancap_Residential_Property e 
    JOIN sancap_Agent r ON e.ListingAgentID=r.AgentID
    JOIN sancap_Office d ON e.ListingFirmID=d.firmID
    WHERE ListingFirmID != 'BrokerC'
```

The data looks like this, the ListingID information being unique is why I believe the query is showing the Agent ID. How do I overcome this?

```
Buck      |     Rogers     |     buck@rogers.com     |     656565      |      BrokerAA
Buck      |     Rogers     |     buck@rogers.com     |     787878      |      BrokerAA
Pamm      |     Feeets     |     pamm@feeets.com     |     999999      |      BrokerBB
```

The result I'd like is this:

```
Buck      |     Rogers     |     buck@rogers.com     |     656565      |      BrokerAA
Pamm      |     Feeets     |     pamm@feeets.com     |     999999      |      BrokerBB
```

Comment: And the result should be?

Comment: Does `GROUP BY r.AgentID` work?

Comment: Updated to show desired result.  YES!  Thanks so much Joe, I'll go read up more on GROUP BY.  Thanks!

Comment: `DISTINCT` works on **all** columns of the result. And your result has no duplicates with regard to that rule. Grouping only by single column is invalid SQL and every other DBMS will reject that. You should be aware of the consequences: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better try `Group by` and `min()` function

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, r.Email, min(ListingID) as ListingID, ListingFirmID
    FROM sancap_Residential_Property e 
    JOIN sancap_Agent r ON e.ListingAgentID = r.AgentID
    JOIN sancap_Office d ON e.ListingFirmID = d.firmID
    WHERE ListingFirmID != 'BrokerC'
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, r.Email, ListingFirmID
```

With above query you will get distinct combination of `FirstName, LastName, r.Email, ListingFirmID` along with minimum value of `ListingID`.

Answer (score 2):

try like this.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, r.Email, ListingID, ListingFirmID
    FROM sancap_Residential_Property e 
    JOIN sancap_Agent r ON e.ListingAgentID=r.AgentID
    JOIN sancap_Office d ON e.ListingFirmID=d.firmID
    WHERE ListingFirmID != 'BrokerC'
group by FirstName, LastName, r.Email,ListingFirmID
```

Comment: If only email should be distinct (as I understand), it's sufficient to leave `r.Email` in the `GROUP BY` clause, which should speed up the grouping. Hmm?

Comment: Bear in mind this will return an undetermined `ListingID` from the group. @Kleskowy, true, but it could be considered better to list all the non-aggregate columns in the GROUP BY for this reason (I doubt it'll speed up the grouping considerably). I prefer Ambrish's answer, but there is a distinct lack of normalisation in the data structure that is leading to these problems.